# Detecting a click on the UIImagePickerController's cancel button?

Tags: button, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality, cancellation

My AR app allows users to capture photos via the camera. Is there a way to detect if the user opened the camera and then clicked the 'cancel button' instead of capturing a photo? I need to refresh the scene if view the user clicks on the cancel button, otherwise, the scene gets stuck.

Here is how I call the camera:

```
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
            myPickerController.delegate = self
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```